# How to maximize the profit

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity

In CLRS , under the section "Maximum sub array problem", there is a problem to maximize the profit in the stock exchange. The problem is.. given an array ***A[1..n]*** and we have to find ***i*** and ***j*** such that ***i < j*** and ***A[j] - A[i]*** should be maximum. the solution given is **O(n^2)** . But I have a solution which does it in **O(n)** . I know it should be wrong , But I cant find a single counter example to my solution.

My solution :

(i) Find the maximun and minimum in **A[1..n]** . Let ***A[x]*** be the maximum and ***A[y]*** be the minimum.

(ii) And find minimum in ***A[1..x]*** . Let that be ***A[u]***.

(iii)Find maximum in ***A[y..n]*** . Let that be ***A[v]***.

(iV) Answer = **Max{(A[x]-A[u]),(A[v]-A[y])}**

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Counter example

Consider the array $A=[5,2,3,4,1]$, where $n=5$.

(i) Then $A[1]=5$ is the maximum and $x=1$, $A[5]=1$ is the minimum and $y=5$.

(ii) And find minimum in $A[1 .. x] = A[1 .. 1]=A[1]$ which is $5$. So, $u=1$.

(iii) Find maximum in $A[y..n] = A[5..5]= A[5]$ which is $1$. So, $v=5$.

(iv)  Answer is $$\max(A[x]-A[u]),(A[v]-A[y]) = \max(A[1]-A[1], A[5]- A[5])= \max(0,0)=0$$

But the maximum profit is $A[4] - A[2] = 2$.

#### $O(n)$ solution

The idea is to start with two pointers $i=1$ and $j=2$ and at each step increase $j$ by one. At each step check if the difference $A[j] - A[j]$ is greater than the maximum profit. If it is then update the maximum profit. But if $A[i] > A[j]$ (in which case $A[j] - A[j]$ is negative and max profit is not updated) then we make $i$ point to the same location $j$ points to, since if for some $k > j$, $A[k] - A[i]$ is greater than the current maximum profit then $A[k] - A[j] > A[k] - A[i] > maxprofit$.

1. Set $i=1$, $j=2$, $maxprofit=0$
2. If $A[j] - A[i] > maxprofit$ then set $maxprofit = A[j] - A[i]$
3. If $A[i] > A[j]$ then set $i = j$
4. $j = j + 1$
5. If $j>n$ return $maxprofit$
6. Goto 2

Comment: Yes. Can't it be better.

Comment: Good question!!! Does not [Kadane's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem) give any idea?